# Генерация разметки со случайными числами

Tags: javascript

Вот код JS:

```
function add(test) {
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = document.getElementById('test').innerHTML + '<table style='float:left; width:100px;'><tbody><tr><td><a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='useract(' + usercnt + ',event);return false;'><center>' + test + '</center><br><img src='тут рандом'></a></td></tr></tbody></table>';
userlist[usercnt] = test;
usercnt++;
}
```

В разметке присутствует следующий код: `<img src="тут рандом">`. Как возможно организовать рандомное число в JS коде от 1 до 3, т.е `<img src="1">, <img src="2">, <img src="3">`

Помогите, пожалуйста. Возможно-ли вообще такое?

Заранее, огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте для этого функции Math:

```
max = 3;
str = "";

for (i = 0; i < max; i++)​ {
    str += "<img src=\"" + Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + 1) + "\" />";  
}

console.log(str)​​;
```

На выходе:

```
<img src="2" /><img src="3" /><img src="2" />
```

Comment: А как это будет выглядеть в моей функции? Я просто в JS новичок. Подскажите, пожалуйста!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
function generate(max){
str = "";

for (i = 0; i < max; i++)​ {
    str += "<img src=\"" + Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + 1) + "\" />";  
}

return str​​;
}
function add(test) {
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML += "
<table style='float:left; width:100px;'><tbody><tr><td>
<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='useract('" + usercnt + "',event);return false;'><center>'" + test + "'</center><br><img src='"+generate(3)+"'></a></td></tr></tbody></table>';
userlist[usercnt] = test;
usercnt++;
}
```